# I am not getting notifications on comment answers

Tags: support, comments, notifications, global-inbox

Since yesterday I am not getting anymore notifications when someone replies to a comment. Before I was getting the red circle beside "inbox" tag.

Anyone knows if it's due to some reason or it's happening from time to time?

btw: even when I reload the page I don't see new notifications and the inbox isn't updated. The new received comment is visible though.

Comment: Any examples of such missed notifications?

Comment: For example a user replied here but I don't see notification in my inbox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853333/saving-a-xml-as-string-in-nvarcharmax-column-getting-truncated

Comment: I see only comments by you there. Am I missing something? Perhaps if comments are removed, the notification goes as well? (No idea if that's the case).

Comment: I am sorry! I put the wrong link, here's the right one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852459/passing-a-variable-into-a-url#comment26062324_17852459

Comment: The user who commented didn't use `@` so no notification should have been sent. All is good.

Comment: Check your inbox now, I posted comment with proper `@`.

Comment: I got that! I receive notifications only when I comment my own post if the users don't use @. Right?

Comment: No. Read the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/152859) to learn everything, in short in case you comment on a question you will get notification if it's only you and the OP "talking". In case of a third user, only `@` will cause a notification. I didn't get notified of your last comment either, only checked here by chance.

Comment: A last question: did I mention you correctly in my answer, replacing spaces with "-"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question solved. I din't know the details on comment @replies.

The answer is here:

[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Thanks to @ShaWizDowArd.